# servlet filtering between web applications

Tags: websphere, servlet-filters

I will explain my question a bit more:

Suppose I have a Web Application 'A' installed in my server (WAS 7 Server specifically). Suppose I have another web application 'B' installed on a different node in my WAS 7 Server.

now, what I would like to know is this: could I create a servlet filter in Application 'A' that intercepts HTTP requests made to applications 'B'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, even if they were running in the same JVM, the filters that apply are ones that are configured in the webapp that the incoming request has been mapped to.

Comment: Thank you very much I thought that too, I wanted to confirm it. I would upvote your answer but I do not have enough reputation. Thank you again.